# CookieSyncManager::createInstance() IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

My app started getting a lot of CookieSyncManager exceptions recently:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CookieSyncManager::createInstance() 
    needs to be called before CookieSyncManager::getInstance()
at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.getInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:81)
at android.webkit.CookieManager$2.run(CookieManager.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

The error is clear from the stack trace, but where it's originating from is not (this is from Play store reporting). The user messages attached to the stack traces indicate that it's happening around the place I'm using the facebook SDK, and it does use CookieSyncManager:

```
// From Facebook.java
private void startDialogAuth(Activity activity, String[] permissions) {
    ...
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity); // <-- here
    dialog(activity, LOGIN, params, new DialogListener() {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync(); // <-- here
            ...
```

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java#L342

This looks ok to me, but is there anything wrong with the above usage? I can't reproduce the error on any of my test devices, perhaps there's an implementation difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be like exception says:

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
   CookieSyncManager.createInstance( activity );    // <-- this line was missing
   CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per android document

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(MainActivity.this);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
}
public void onReume(){
    super.onResume();
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync();
}
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
```